# How to install Windows 10 additionally to OS X and Ubuntu (triple-boot)?

Tags: windows, unix, dual-boot, efi

I have installed Ubuntu separately from OS X. rEFInd is already installed. Now I need to install Windows 10. I've created a separate partition for this in OS X. If I try to install Windows from USB, will rEFind recognize this? If not, how should I install Windows properly?

P.S. MacBookPro9,2

Comment: This depend on the model/year of your Mac. Also, it would be helpful to know the name of the iso file you used to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that will work! Jus remember to download the specific drivers for your model on apples website download page, then pass them to an USB stick and install the software on your windows partition, also of your using an ISO or disk image I would recommend CAREFULLY using the dd command, boot the drive and install to the partition, then boot back to os x, get the drivers and then boot to the windows 10 partition, configure windows and install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it before with rEFInd (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

You should get some guides though, order in OS installation is important to avoid problems and headaches with Bootcamp.

Good Luck!

If you want to avoid the hassle to have 3 partitions in one Laptop's disk, Virtual Machines may be your thing.